# How to pass a query param to Devise's login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Devise customisation issue that I'm struggling with.

We have a query parameter included in some email links that need to be passed to the login URL if the user is not already authenticated when they click on the link. For example, if the email link is:

```
http://my.host.com/my/path/1234?x=y&foo=bar
```

I'd like unauthenticated users to be redirected to

```
http://my.host.com/login/?foo=bar
```

i.e., one specific query param *needs* to be passed – I don't care about any others on the login form, but if all the query params have to be passed I could live with that.

I've scoured SO, and the docs & source for both Devise and Warden, but can't find a straightforward way of doing this. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, we got the effect we wanted by going down a very slightly different route.

Rather than including the param in the query URL of the redirect to the login, we were able to modify the code concerned to accept a session parameter instead.

Then, in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :persist_login_param
  ...

  def persist_login_param
    session[:foo] = params[:foo]
  end
end
```

And in the sessions controller, we act upon the value of the session parameter, discarding it once done.

Slightly messy, but it works and gets code pushed out to production now, which is the important thing!

Comment: I don't think this works for unauthenticated users. Devise will redirect them to the login page before the `before_filter` has a chance to act. At least this is what I'm finding in my own setup with Devise 2.0.4 and Rails 2.2.2.

Comment: Nevermind, this does work! You just have to make sure `:persist_login_param` comes before `:authenticate_user!` in the `before_filter` chain. Thanks, Scott.

Answer (score 1):

Can use unless statement in before_action, then unauthentication users can see any devise controller actions

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  before_filter :sending_params
  before_action :check_auth, unless: :devise_controller?

  ...

  protected

  def check_auth
    unless user_signed_in?
      redirect_to new_user_session_path(sending_params)
    end
  end

  def sending_params
    params.permit(:first_param, :second_param)
  end
  ...
```

And can access to params without generation devise controllers by generate devise views and use in views

```
<%= params[:first_param] %>
```

If need send params to omniauth controller, you can change link in devise views

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in by provider', omniauth_authorize_path(:user, :provider, first_param: params['first_param']) %>
```

Where :user - name devise model, :provider - name omniauth provider (:facebook i.e.)

In omniauth controller you can use

```
 def first_param
   request.env['omniauth.params']['first_param'] ||= ''
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

For an unauthenticated user, in order to pass specific params `foo=bar` out of `http://my.host.com/my/path/1234?x=y&foo=bar` to your login, perform as below:

Assuming the above email link goes to action `myaction` then add the following code to `myaction`

```
  def myaction
    if member_signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      ## If user is unauthenticated direct them to login page with specific params
      redirect_to new_member_session_path(foo: params[:foo]) 
    end
  end
```

Above action will pass params `foo` to the devise login page and the actual link in browser address bar would look as below:

```
http://my.host.com/login?foo=bar  ## Without / after login
```

You can access the param by overridding Devise::SessionsController. For Example :

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  ...
  def new
    @foo = params[:foo]
    super
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, because authentication happens further up the call stack, in this instance #myaction never gets called unless the user has already been authenticated.